# Android Emulator Emulator the specific screen solution

Tags: android, size, screen, emulation

hi guys this question may seem to be very simple but really i dont know the answer. All that i need is to stimulate the screen size of [this motorola mobile](http://www.motorola.com/Consumers/US-EN/Consumer-Product-and-Services/Mobile-Phones/MOTOROLA-PHOTON-4G-US-EN)

And i have developed the app in the HVGA Mode in emulator and it is fine but when i change the screen size to 540X960 my app design cuts according to the images that i have... Currently my have my images for 540 X 960 in hdpi...  Looking for the better responses...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

follow the guidelines which are provided by the android team 
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html